# Yes/No questionnaire analysis

Tags: r, survey

I have a dataset from a class taught in two different ways, groupwork or lectures, and they chose which one they preferred after the first lesson and then again after the second lesson.

I'm not sure the best way to analyse this potential change in preference; the data is all anonymous and not paired from the 1st questionnaire to the 2nd one.

I'm not great with stats so any help greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Unfortunately if you can't link responses to participants across the questionnaires, you cannot investigate changes in preferences (expect at the whole sample level - e.g. which proportion of participants preferred teaching method A after lesson 1, and which proportion after lesson 2).

Comment: Is there some additional information that can be used to do some partial matching?